iwd/iwctl: how to disable AutoConnect
When I use iwctl to connect to a new network, it adds that as a known network and sets the AutoConnect property to true. I do not like this behavior. If my laptop automatically reconnects to untrusted networks such as those provided by coffee shops, airports, etc, IMO that is a security issue.
How can I make iwd not do this? Where are the defaults? If the only way to do this is modifying iwd's source, I'll do that but it would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

in the /etc/iwd/main.conf file, as long as the config file specific to the WiFi we want to not connect to, e.g. /var/lib/iwd/whatever.psk, override that with AutoConnect=false
source
